# Is it possible to calculate the shift vector of two vector?

Tags: vectors, matlab, computational-mathematics, image-processing

I'm working on some image processing tasks and I'm required to **calculate the 'shift vector' of two feature vectors**. I'm not entirely sure what 'shift vector' really means as i just came across it, but googling gave me pretty much irrelevant searches and just recently i came across this source, which i assume is mathematically defined 'shift vector'. http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/geometry/Lectures/A4.html

I would like to know what **shift vector** really does and how do i **calculate the shift vector of two similar vectors**.

If i have two vectors(made up),

$v_1 = (43, 20, 10)$

$v_2 = (40, 16, 8)$

**Note**: normally, the image feature vectors can be represented in the form:

```
first_feature = [34 30 10 15 27 67]
second_feature = [30 28 6 13 25 60]
```

Is there any formula that i could use to calculate the shift vector between the two vectors above?

I'm totally new to vectors and would appreciate some help on this.